# Troubles with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I can't figure out what goes wrong. i just create the poject to test HtmlAgilityPack and what i've got.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


namespace parseHabra
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HTTP net = new HTTP(); //some http wraper
            string result = net.MakeRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/", null);
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(result);

            //Get all summary blocks
            HtmlNodeCollection news = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"summary\"]");
            foreach (HtmlNode item in news)
            {
                string title = String.Empty;
                //trouble is here for each element item i get the same value
                //all the time
                title = item.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class=\"question-hyperlink\"]").InnerText.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine(title);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like i make xpath not for each node i've selected but to whole document. Any suggestions why it so ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using `HtmlWeb` to download the HTML directly?

Comment: For this issue it's not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried your code, but from the quick look I suspect the problem is that the `//` is searching from the root of the entire document and not the root of the current element as I guess you are expecting.

Try putting a `.` before the `//`

```
".//a[@class=\"question-hyperlink\"]"
```

Comment: But how it can be, the content in selected node is just a part of htmldocument or not ???

Comment: @imbriarius, when you select a node it is not isolated from the rest of the document, therefore `//` still remains relative to the entire document. Using `.//` means anywhere from here down, the `.` selects the current node.

Comment: Thx a lot i don't know what i've to do without ur help

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite your xpath as a single query to find all the question titles, rather than finding the summaries *then* the titles.  Chris' answer points out the problem which could have easily been avoided.

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://stackoverflow.com");

var xpath = "//div[starts-with(@id,'question-summary-')]//a[@class='question-hyperlink']";

var questionTitles = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes(xpath)
    .Select(a => a.InnerText.Trim());
```

Comment: For me more important to understand library behavior